# How to load external URL into modal jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery

I need to load the url in a modal UI Box using Jquery
I get to load the modal but i cant show the page loaded in url

I need to show the anylink in a UI Dialog

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I have no I need to know with code how it is done

Comment: unfortunately this is not a free coding service, I advise you to search into the web better. If you find something specific difficult, don't hesitate to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're trying to load. Is it another html page, or in Dot Net, an ASPX page? Do you need callbacks from that page to function? If it's ASPX, do you need it to handle postpacks appropriately for server-side functions to work? If so, that's where things get tricky.

But, the easiest way is mainly passing in the URL of the page/document you want to load to the dialog open function. This is the JavaScript code that you would execute when you're ready to display a dialog.

The "#dialogExample" is the ID of a div in your html with "id" set to "dialogExample". This gives jQuery-UI a place to display the external page/document. It can be as simple as . This will not display the div until you call the JavaScript function below (such as via a button on your main HTML page that calls the code below).

```
var url = "some url to form or page you want to load";

$("#dialogExample").dialog( {
    open: function() {
        $(this).load(url);
    },
    close: function(e) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this.dialog("destroy");
    },
});
```

But this is a very crude and simple example. Things get more intricate if you're looking to use ASPX pages, or want to pass values back and forth between the main form and the dialog using callbacks, etc. This particular example is fine if you want to pop up a simple confirm dialog that has no functionality in it.

Best bet is to go to the jquery-ui web page and read up on jQuery-ui dialogs there. They have plenty of examples on things, but again, they are very simple examples that cover common things. The more complicated you need to get, the more searching you're going to need to do.

Search the internet. There are plenty of examples out there.